# why i need three await key word can get correct result?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, jscript

```js
const state = {
  data: ''
}

const axios = async () => {
  console.log('can getData')
  return 'babc'
}

const fenchItem = async () => {
  return axios()
}

const action = () => {
  console.log('call get')
  fenchItem().then((data) => {
    state.data = data
    console.log('set value')
  })
}

const result = async () => {
  await await await action()
  console.log('state value is ', state.data)
}

result()
```

From code i want state.data get correct result, i don't know why i need three await key word. Anybody can help me? Thanks.

```
call get
can getData
set value
state value is  babc
```

this is result what i want to get. If I remove one await , state value will be null.

Comment: The real question is... Why are you using `async` *at all* here?  There are no asynchronous operations taking place.  It looks like this code was written to be as obtuse as it could be, which doesn't help anybody understand it.  As soon as you start to refactor out the `async` keywords that aren't needed, you eventually find that you don't need any of them and then there's nothing to `await`.

Comment: It is a demo code for me, I used vuejs for my project. In my project, I use vuex to get remote data. but in unit testing, i found i have to use three await to get correct result. I don't know why.